# Update on CTE with Row_Number Value not working as expected

Tags: t-sql

I'm working in SQL Server 2016, I'm trying to UPDATE records in a CTE given the ROW_NUMBER value.  Any help/direction would be appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my SQL code:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT a04.RecordId, a04.AccountNumber, a04.PhoneType, a04.Active --, a04.AreaCode, a04.TelephoneNumber
        , RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a04.AccountNumber ORDER BY a04.AccountNumber ASC)
    FROM dbo.A04_AccountPhones a04
    WHERE a04.PhoneType = 'RRT'
    AND a04.AccountNumber = 777782
    --ORDER BY a04.AccountNumber ASC, a04.RecordId DESC;
)
UPDATE c
SET c.Active = 0
--SELECT c.*
FROM CTE c
WHERE c.RN > 1;

SELECT a04.RecordId, a04.AccountNumber, a04.PhoneType, a04.Active, a04.AreaCode, a04.TelephoneNumber
    , RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a04.AccountNumber ORDER BY a04.AccountNumber ASC)
FROM dbo.A04_AccountPhones a04
WHERE a04.PhoneType = 'RRT'
AND a04.AccountNumber = 777782
ORDER BY a04.AccountNumber ASC, a04.RecordId DESC;
```

Before the UPDATE is executed the records are as follows:

[image: RecordId AccountNumber PhoneType Active RN 5803964 777782 RRT 1 1 5802727 777782 RRT 1 2 5533020 777782 RRT 1 3]

After the UPDATE the WRONG records are updated as I am supposed to update the records where RN > 1:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I am assuming it has to do with ROW_NUMBER but I'm having a problem trying fix it.

Comment: Your window function is ordering by the same column it's partitioned on - this is non-deterministic, should you be ordering by RecordId?

Comment: Given that you're computing two distinct row_number values (one in the update, one in the select), ordering on a column that has always the same values makes the assignment of those rownums non-deterministic (in fact your second rownum values happen to be different wrt your first rownum values).

Comment: Thank you @Stu and lemon.  I didn't see it.  Your help and time are appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

What happens if instead of updating the CTE, you join the actual table you want to update to the CTE:

```
UPDATE dbo.A04_AccountPhones
SET a04.Active = 0
--SELECT c.*
FROM dbo.A04_AccountPhones a04
inner join  CTE c on a04.RecordId = c.RecordId
WHERE c.RN > 1;
```